# Trying to bind form2 textbox to form1 listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have winform1 with `ListView` and add button. When I press add button it opens new winform2 that have 2 textboxes in it, name and surname, and save button.
Now what I want is to add these values to the listView when I press save. I get no errors in code but my listbox won't update.

Here is code for my list class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the form2 code:

```
public partial class add : Form
{
    public add()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = textBox1.Text;
        p.Surname = textBox2.Text;
        People.Add(p);
        f2.listView1.Items.Add(p.Name + " " + p.Surname);
    }
}
```

Now the thing is that debugging does not show any errors. My listbox1 does not update and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Tried using `f2.ShowDialog();` then it shows added items in listview but it opens form1 again and when I add new data the previous data will be lost. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Your code won't compile since there is a reference to member f2 in your button1_Click code - are you sure you haven't made a typo in your code? Also this isn't strictly "binding", as you are not using any bindings. You are just literally adding the items directly to the listview. My bet is on the fact that you are creating a new Form1 inside Form2 then adding to Form1 listview. I'm assuming Form1 is created first, which opens Form2 - you should pass Form1 to Form2 or write your listbox addition code in Form1. What's the point of the People list? It's private - it's all a bit confusing tbh!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure that the `Person` in the `add` form is available to the caller, `Form1` so that when the user clicks the OK button, you can add that info into the listview.

For simplicity, I've changed my version to add a single item. I leave it up to you to figure out how to do the same for a `List<Person>`.

In code, that would look something like this:

```
public partial class add : Form
{
    // notice that we don't need a List, just a single item
    public Person person = new Person();

    public add()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.person.Name = this.nameTextBox.Text;
        this.person.Surname = this.surnameTextBox.Text;

        // the listView is only be updated if the changes were accepted
        // setting the result to OK will also close the dialog
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

And the code for `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var add = new add();

        if (add.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.listView1.Items.Add(add.person.Name +
                                     " " + add.person.Surname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1396678 if this code useful for you then please give an upvote to thank to Gustavo's answer..then so everyone has excited to answer all the questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your textboxes :

```
public string textbox1_text
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
```

Use these codes for loading new form :

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Owner = this;
        f2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be wrong:

```
f2.listView1.Items.Add(p.Name + " " + p.Surname); //Form2
```

Maybe do you mean:

```
f1.Show();
f1.listView1.Items.Add(p.Name + " " + p.Surname); //Form1
//this.Close(); <-- if you want to close the form after show f1
```

?